# How can I convert EventArgs to PaintEventArgs, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

I want to call *OnPaint()* when MCU_timer_Tick() is called.
How can I do?

```
    private void MCU_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      Graphics g = e.Graphics;

      int width = 30;
      int x, y;
      x = 150;
      y = 530;
      double color_max;
      color_max = 255;
      SolidBrush aBrush_1 = 
        new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 
        (int)(255 * color_map[0] / color_max), 0)); //color_map[0] is real value
      g.FillEllipse(aBrush_1, x-100, y, width * 2, width);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `this.Invalidate()` in `Tick` event. That will eventually make the Paint event happen.

```
private void MCU_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

where `this` refers to a `Control`. Typically a `Form`.